# Is there a way to do a fuzzy search using IBM Watson Discovery?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-discovery

I have a prototype using IBM Watson Discovery. I need to know if fuzzy search is supported and how to configure it. Anyone knows? besides, I'd like to know what is the search engine used by Discovery (if there is one).

Answer (score 0):

You can apply and search with [different operators in Watson Discovery queries](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/discovery?topic=discovery-query-operators#variation). Note that applying [fuzzy search has performance impact](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/discovery?topic=discovery-qp).